# revert back to last commit in git branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have the following branches

1. master
2. photos
3. email

My problem is that I have merged `master` branch into `photos` branch  and the conflict occurred because I made changes to the same file. Then I `reset --hard HEAD` and `photos` branch back to default when first created.
How to change back `photos` branch into last commit before merge with `master` branch ?

I want to use `git checkout HEAD` but I cannot find history or log git of branch `photos`.

Comment: This is impossible situation. `git reset --hard HEAD` resets your current selected branch into the commit where branch point at know. It is last commit of that branch. There is now way you loose photos state after resetting it in a merge conflict. Please make sure that you've committed your previous changes into `photos` branch.

Comment: yes i have been commit into photos branch before, now my problem is fix :)

Answer (score 3):

You may try looking in the `git reflog` to see if you can find that commit, then `git reset --hard <commit>` to restore your branch.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at `git reflog photos` to see modifications to where the `photos` branch has been pointing. Find the one before the merge, and `reset --hard` to that instead of `HEAD`.

Comment: `git reflog photos` didn't show anything just show this `usage: git reflog [ show | expire | delete ]` and actually I am never push last commit in photos branch, now I cann't found where last commit head?

it's possible can be restore ? or not?

Comment: If `git reflog photos` didn't show anything, you might double-check and see if you actually have a `photos` branch. (Look at the output of `git branch`.)

Comment: ah ok I found I am forget not add option show `git reflog show photos`